# Comparison of two cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to write a formula in excel.

**Condition:**

*If cells BL4 and BM4 will be equal to "Done", it will output the text "Done" in cell BN4, and if the first condition is not fulfilled, it will output the number from filled fields from N4 to BI4 in cell BN4.*

**My solution:**

```
=IF(AND(A1="Done"=B1="Done");"Done";COUNTIF(C1:F1))
```

*The first condition is not fulfilled.*

Comment: In your post you have mentioned `BL4`, `BM4` and `BN4` while the formula you are using referring to other cells, perhaps i would use `SUM()` instead of `COUNTA()` because if one of the cells from `N4` to `BI4` is not really empty it would count those cells as well, `IF((BL4="Done")*(BM4="Done"),"Done",SUM(--(N4:BI4<>"")))` also the syntax of `COUNTIF()` is wrong i dont know how Excel was letting you the enter the formula without giving you a error pop up as it is missing the `criteria` in `COUNTIF()` function

Answer (score 1):

Mostly formatting or syntax fixes.
Use `COUNTA()` for counting non-empty cells.
Try this:

```
=IF(AND(A1="Done",B1="Done"),"Done",COUNTA(C1:F1))
```